# How to get size of python opcode

Tags: python, opcode

I am parsing python bytecodes (co_code). For some operation I want to know the length of python opcodes in bytes. Where can I find the length of python opcodes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python bytecode and .pyc file format specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229387/python-bytecode-and-pyc-file-format-specification)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All CPython bytecode opcodes are 1 byte long. On CPython 3.6+, all opcodes additionally take a 1-byte argument, for a total of 2 bytes per instruction. On previous versions, opcodes less than the special value [HAVE_ARGUMENT](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-HAVE_ARGUMENT) take no argument, and opcodes greater than that value take a 2-byte argument, for a total of 1 or 3 bytes per instruction.

Answer (score 0):

A simple function like this may help:

```
def compute_size(opcode):
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 6):
        return 2
    return (1, 3)[opcode < dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT]
```